# Why do four chickens come out of one egg sometimes when I play minecraft ( bedrock edition )?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Sometimes when you throw eggs, a baby chicken comes out. But what I don't understand is how many baby chickens are supposed to come out of one egg.

I had one experience when the baby stood there for a moment, then four of them walk away. Somehow one egg can just spew out for chickens. But how? And why?

Answer (score 4):

A Minecraft egg has a 1 in 8 chance of spawning a single chicken. If it spawns a chicken, it has a 1 in 32 chance to spawn an additional 3 chickens. That's pretty much everything there is to say about it. Mojang hasn't said anything about why this is. For more information: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Egg#Spawning_chickens